# Spring Data JPA in Multi Tenant Environment

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, spring-data

I'm using a EclipseLink multi tenant solution, documented at:
http://codecrafters.blogspot.it/2013/03/multi-tenant-cloud-applications-with.html

Where I customize and override the methods in my CustomRepository that extends JPARepository to set the Current Tenant Id of user.

It's working but I use some methods to login for example:

```
 User findByUsername(String username);
```

So, this method is not overriden causing a **No value was provided for the session property [OrgId]** exception.

Anyone can see a solution to override all this methods or other alternative?

Thanks folks.

Comment: Unfortunately whilst I have gone past the issue you're having - creating a new repository interface that includes a "setTenantId()" method that picks up the current tenant and pushes it to the entity manager for the eclipselink tenant id property. However, it seems that the very first time the query is created it then is cached, so that any subsequent calls of the query use the cached tenant id, *and* the new one provided in the repository entity manager resulting in a "where tenant = a and tenant = b" query and obviously no results. :( Did you have any luck fixing?